# Will the conquest of India not happen until towards the end time when Prophet Isa returns?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, prophet-isa

> It was narrated that Thawbaan, the freed slave of the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him), said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “There are two groups of my ummah whom Allah will protect from the Fire: a group who will conquer India, and a group who will be with ‘Eesaa ibn Maryam (peace be upon him).”
>
> Narrated by an-Nasaa’i (no. 3175) and Imam Ahmad in al-Musnad (37/81), Mu’sasat ar-Risaalah edn. Classed as hasan by the commentators on al-Musnad. Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in as-Silsilah as-Saheehah (no. 1934)

(See: [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/nasai/25/91).)

There are also reports of this hadith with several chains from Abu Hurayrah which are classed as da'if (weak).

My question is does this hadith mean the conquest of India will not happen now but towards the end time when 'Eesaa ibn Maryam returns??

I have read some interpretations that argue that the two issues are not related (the return of Eesa) and (conquest of india) because India was ruled by Muslims many times, for a long time and they was successful.

Can you please provide explanation of the scholars commentary on this issue and clarify the matter?